# React can't render, got Unterminated JSX contents error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
class HelloWorldComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const person = {"name":"james"};
    return (      
      <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={person.name}>      
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <HelloWorldComponent />, document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

http://jsbin.com/lalomigufo/edit?js,console,output

Not sure what is wrong, I got error of `Unterminated JSX contents` when I try to exam my code in https://babeljs.io

Comment: how about you try terminating your JSX contents? Specifically, that unterminated `input`

Comment: @Hamms ops careless mistake I've made. But why now my input is not editable?

Comment: @Hamms http://jsbin.com/huluqifanu/1/edit?js,console,output

Comment: This is React 101. You will need to change the state of your input value on the onChange event. See react documentation with plenty of examples https://facebook.github.io/react/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input** is a self closing tag. You need to add the "/" at the end of the input element:

```
return (      
  <input type="text" placeholder="name" value={person.name} />      
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the document from [facebook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html):

> In HTML, form elements such as , , and 
> typically maintain their own state and update it based on user input.
> In React, mutable state is typically kept in the state property of
> components, and only updated with setState()

So, your code put the constant value to `value` attribute, it's wrong, this value cannot be changed and you can type anything.